# Select rows from related table which matches different conditions

Tags: sql, rows

I have a table called `places` which looks like this:

[image]

and another table called `place_addons_saved` which looks like this:

[image]

How can I write a query that relates `place_addons_saved.place` and `places.id` and searches rows that matches ONLY places which have all the conditions?

For example when I'll search for rows that have `place_addon = 163`, `place_option = 329` and `place_addon = 162`, `place_option = 324` will return place with id of a `80`, but when I'll search for rows that have `place_addon = 162`, `place_option = 326` and `place_addon = 163`, `place_option = 330` the query must return nothing, because place 80 doesn't fit the 2nd condition

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select place
from place_addons_saved
where (place_addon = 163 and place_option = 329) or
      (place_addon = 162 and place_option = 324)
group by place
having count(*) = 2;  -- "2" is the number of comparisons
```

To get all the information about the places:

```
select p.*
from places p
where p.id in (select place
               from place_addons_saved
               where (place_addon = 163 and place_option = 329) or
                     (place_addon = 162 and place_option = 324)
               group by place
               having count(*) = 2;  -- "2" is the number of comparisons
              );
```

Comment: yes yes yes, that's what I was searching for but not exactly, I also wanna make relation such as `place_addons_saved.place = places.id` and I wanna get data only from `places` table

Comment: You can use `in`, `exists` or ` join` to bring in columns from `places`.

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: second query gives me 1 row output instead of two :( (for example 1st query gives back 2 ids, but only 1 is showed in 2nd query)

Answer (score 0):

### This could work:

```
With GetResult (place,chk1,chk2) As
(
SELECT 
   pas.place,
   sum(Case When (pas.place_addon = 163) AND (pas.place_option = 329) then 1 Else 0 End) As chk1,
   sum(Case When (pas.place_addon = 162) AND (pas.place_option = 324) then 1 Else 0 End) As chk2
FROM 
   places AS p RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   place_addons_saved AS pas ON p.id = pas.place
   group by pas.place
 )
 Select * From GetResult Where chk1 > 0 and chk2 > 0
```